# Filter using the workflow status column

Tags: list-view

I want to create a view for a Sharepoint list and filter it based on the workflow status column. My idea is to show only the items with the status "Waiting for Approval" in a view, in order to create a list that will be discussed in meeting.

The problem is that the workflow status column is not present in the dropdown menu that is used to filter (below "Show items only when the following is true" topic).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you create additional column in your list and in WF set value of that column based on WF status. By that you could replicate what you need.

Comment: Did you published your workflow? If yes you will find the WF column for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the workflow development, try possible to create a choice column and update the column value when the workflow runs based on state level of sequential, create a view based on the new column